# On the stability of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, stability

I am just learning about stability, but am struggling to convince myself that an ideal gas is stable with respect to perturbations in particle number.

The fundamental equation of an (single-component) ideal gas is

$$S = Ns = S_0 + cNR\ln \left(\frac{U}{U_0}\right) + NR\ln \left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right).$$

As far as I know, to assess stability (locally), we must use that we need to check that every principal submatrix of the Hessian has only negative eigenvalues.

Thus, we form the Hessian of $S$ below:
$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & 0 & cR/U \\
    0 & -NR/V^2 & R/V \\
    cR/U & R/V & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The principle submatrices are threefold: the ones corresponding to ($\Delta$ refers to perturbations in the given variable) $(\Delta U, \Delta V)$, $(\Delta N, \Delta V)$, $(\Delta U, \Delta N)$.These submatrices are
$$H_{U,V} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & 0 \\
    0 & -NR/V^2
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$H_{V,N} = \begin{bmatrix}
   -NR/V^2 & R/V \\
    R/V & 0
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$H_{U,N} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & cR/U \\
    cR/U & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

But as far as I can tell, only $H_{U,V}$ is negative definite -- the others clearly have one positive and one negative eigenvalue. Am I to conclude that an ideal gas is not stable with respect to perturbations $\Delta N$?

**Edit: After hints from Giorgio and naturallyInconsistent, I obtain the following instead:**
The key is that my initial fundamental equation was wrong, and it should instead be (see Callen (3.38)):

$$S = Ns = Ns_0 + cNR\ln \left(\frac{U}{U_0}\right) + NR\ln \left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right) -(c+1)NR\ln \left(\frac{N}{N_0}\right).$$

We form the Hessian:
$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & 0 & cR/U \\
    0 & -NR/V^2 & R/V \\
    cR/U & R/V & -(c+1)R/N
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The principle submatrices are threefold: the ones corresponding to $(\Delta U, \Delta V)$, $(\Delta N, \Delta V)$, $(\Delta U, \Delta N)$. These submatrices are
$$H_{U,V} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & 0 \\
    0 & -NR/V^2
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$H_{V,N} = \begin{bmatrix}
   -NR/V^2 & R/V \\
    R/V & -(c+1)R/N
\end{bmatrix},$$
$$H_{U,N} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -cNR/U^2 & cR/U \\
    cR/U & -(c+1)R/N
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now $H_{U,V}$ is diagonal and so immediately we see that it has negative eigenvalues. The other two are not, but we caan argue as follows. Since each of the other two has a negative trace, there must exist at least one negative eigenvalue (trace equals sum of eigenvalues). Thus, since the determinant equals the product of all the eigenvalues, the other two matrices are negative definite (only negative eigenvalues) if and only if they have positive determinant. Now,
$$\det(H_{V,N}) = (c+1)R^2/V^2 - R^2/V^2 = cR^2/V^2>0,$$
and
$$\det(H_{U,N}) = c(c+1)R^2/U^2 - c^2R^2/U^2 = cR^2/U^2>0.$$
So the ideal gas EOS is locally stable everywhere, and thus globally stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an important conceptual issue that should be clarified when discussing the stability conditions.

As soon as the thermodynamic information contained in the fundamental equation $S(U,V,N)$ is extensive, the hessian matrix of the second derivatives of $S$ with respect to its three variables has a null determinant, implying that (at least) one eigenvalue is zero. This is a consequence of extensiveness, i.e., a mathematical consequence of the fact that the dependence on one of the extensive variables can be transformed into a linear dependence. For instance,
$$
S(U,V,N) = N s(u,v),
$$
where $s(u,v)$ is the energy per particle (or per mole) expressed in terms of energy and volume per particle (or per mole).

As a consequence, the stability conditions corresponding to a definite negative Hessian apply to the Hessian matrix of $s(u,v)$ or the equivalent two-variable functions obtained using $U$ or $V$ as *affine* (linear) variable.

---

*This is an edit of the first short answer. The purpose of the extension is to make some more explicit points. For clarity, I add it to the original answer.*

There is an important conceptual issue that should be clarified when discussing the stability conditions.

If the description of the equilibrium system is encoded into the entropy $S$, as a function of energy ($U$), volume ($V$), and number of moles ($N$), it would be attempting to define *stable* a thermodynamic system such that $S(U,V,N)$ is a strictly concave function of its variables. Indeed, the strict concavity ensures the uniqueness of the equilibrium state.

However, this is impossible because, due to the extensiveness, the Hessian matrix of the second derivatives of $S$ with respect to its three variables always has a null determinant (not only for the perfect gas), implying that one eigenvalue is zero. This is a consequence of extensiveness, i.e., it is a mathematical consequence of the fact that the dependence on one of the extensive variables can be transformed into a linear dependence by a suitable change of variables. For instance,
$$
S(U,V,N) = N s(u,v),
$$
where $s(u,v)$ is the energy per particle (or per mole) expressed in terms of energy and volume per particle (or per mole), $u$ and $v$.
It is a simple exercise to show that, whatever the function $S$, the Hessian of $S(U,V,N) = N s(U/N,V/N)$ contains only two linearly independent rows (or columns). The physical translation of such a mathematical fact is that since
$$
S(2U,2V,2N) = 2N s(U/N,V/N)
$$
and
$$
S(3U,3V,3N) = 3N s(U/N,V/N)
$$
we have
$$
S(2U,2V,2N)=\frac{S(U,V,N)+S(3U,3V,3N)}{2}
$$
preventing entropy from being strictly convex. For this reason, stability (strict convexity) is checked by keeping one of the three variables constant to exclude such a trivial effect.

As a consequence, the stability conditions corresponding to a negative definite Hessian apply to the Hessian of $s(u,v)$ or the other equivalent two-variable functions obtained using $U$ or $V$ as *affine* (linear) variable:
$$
\begin{align}
S(U,V,N) &= V \tilde s\left( \frac{U}{V},\frac{N}{V}\right)&= V \tilde s\left( \tilde u,\tilde n)\right)\\
S(U,V,N) &= U \bar s\left( \frac{V}{U},\frac{N}{U}\right)&= U \bar s\left( \bar v,\bar n)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Once one has checked the negative definiteness of the Hessian of, say,  $\bar s\left( \frac{V}{U},\frac{N}{U}\right)$, this implies the usual stability conditions on $S(U,V,N)$, and in particular with respect to perturbations of $N$, explicitly excluding the cases such that $U/N=$constant and $V/N=$constant.

Comment: Oh yeah, nice answer, take my upvote. You explained why it must be negative semi-definite

Comment: Noted, and I agree -- I think that's what I was trying to get at with consideration of the 3 principal submatrices in turn. But what I find is that, even considering the principial submatrices, when I look at a principal submatrix involving $N$ I do not get a negative definite matrix (as I should). For example, $det(H_{V,N}) = -(R/V)^2$ which tells us this matrix has one positive and one negative eigenvalue, contradicting that it should be negative definite! Surely the mistake is somewhere in my Hessian, or is there something special about $N$ in an ideal gas?

Comment: @EE18 You simply are not supposed to be considering the Hessian submatrices that way. Illegal. What Giorgio correctly pointed out, is that you should be expressing them as $S=Ns(u,v)$, where then $s$ is negative definite in its arguments, and then consider $S=Us^\prime(\frac1u,\frac VU)$, where than $s^\prime$ is negative definite in its arguments, and so on.

Comment: On this I do not agree with you. Per Rau Chapter 5.2, this is precisely how one is meant to consider stability against perturbations in *every* type of extensive variable ("resource", as he calls it). What you are describing would only be a check against perturbations in energy and volume. @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: This is also encoded in Giorgio's last comment I believe: "...or the equivalent two-variable functions obtained using $U$ or $V$ as affine (linear) variable." That is, I believe Giorgio is saying that a check on stability must include consideration of each extensive variable as the affine variable.

Comment: @EE18 if you read both mine and Giorgio's answer, you will see that two of the variables has the negative definiteness as you wanted, but the 3rd necessarily will have eigenvalue zero. Hence why my first comment here upon reading Giorgio's answer is about negative semi-definiteness. Look, if you can show that all three different types of intensive entropy functions of the three different pairings of variables are negative definite, then you have also proved that it is a maximum. This is the best you can hope for because doing all 3 at once is not possible, by thermodynamic relations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147188/discussion-between-ee18-and-naturallyinconsistent).

Answer (score 0):

You nearly gave me an aneurysm when you wrote with $NR$ rather than $Nk_B$ or $nR$

The 2nd partial derivative test, i.e. using Hessian, is inconclusive, and I am loathe to go to even higher orders.

Your Hessian is actually wrong. Let us start with Sackur-Tetrode, as you did.
\begin{align}
\tag1\frac S{k_B}&=N\ln\left[\frac VN\left(\frac{4\pi m}{3h^2}\frac UN\right)^c\right]+(1+c)N\\
\tag2&=N\ln V+cN\ln U-N(1+c)\ln N+(1+c)N+N\ln B\\
\tag3H&=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{cN}{U^2}&&\frac cU\\&-\frac N{V^2}&\frac1V\\\frac cU&\frac1V&-\frac{1+c}N\end  {pmatrix}
\end{align}
We can now apply Sylvester's criterion on this Hessian to note that, yes, the $U$ and $V$ parts are obviously negative definite and thus stable, but the $N$ part is inconclusive because it has a zero eigenvalue there.

I do not see why you have to do this; we postulated that the entropy function is going to be a maximum at equilibrium...

Comment: Oy, you are right, and the error is that my fundamental equation is wrong! I am missing a $\ln N$ term. Thank you, I will reassess right now. In terms of why I have to do this, I am not sure -- I am just learning about stability but surely it will be relevant!

Comment: BTW, $NR$ is Callen's notation; I can't help but use it given that I'm studying it :)

Comment: I am literally in shock. I had to flip open my own copy and _shudder_

Comment: Yes, it is a curious decision by Callen to use $N$ for moles, but perhaps that’s because it’s an old book.